# Print Subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I have problem with function Popen. I try retrieving the output from command which i used.

```
print(subprocess.Popen("dig -x 156.17.86.3 +short", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].decode('utf-8').strip())
```

This part working, but when I call the variable inside `Popen` (for adress in IP)

`print(subprocess.Popen("dig -x ",Adres," +short", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].decode('utf-8').strip())`

happens something like that:

```
raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
```

I thought it would be problem with command so I used this solution:

```
command=['dig','-x',str(Adres),'+short']
        print(subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].decode('utf-8').strip())
```

But now the return values is different than from console :

```
dig -x 156.17.4.20 +short
vpn.ii.uni.wroc.pl.
```

How I can print this the above name in script ?
Thank a lot of

Comment: different how? your first 2 attempts don't work because you're passing the arguments as arguments of `Popen`. Your third attempt is the closest one, but tell us the output (by printing `communicate` output you're printing output & error streams as a tuple and as bytes. Is that your issue?

Comment: The output what I expect is that like from command, on the third attempt script print wrong server (like didnt see IpAdress)

Comment: The third one is still wrong, because you're passing a list but using `shell=True`. See my answer; it's too hard to explain everything in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that you're not passing a single string, but multiple separate arguments:

```
subprocess.Popen("dig -x ",Adres," +short", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

If you look at [the `Popen` constructor in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), that means you're passing `"dig -x"` as the `args` string, passing `Adres` as the `bufsize`, and passing `"+short"` as the `executable`. That's definitely not what you want.

You could fix this by building a string with concatenation or string formatting:

```
subprocess.Popen("dig -x " + str(Adres) + " +short", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
subprocess.Popen(f"dig -x {Adres} +short", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

However, a much better fix is to just not use the shell here, and pass the arguments as a list:

```
subprocess.Popen(['dig', '-x', Adres, '+short'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Notice that if you do this, you have to remove the `shell=True`, or this won't work. (It *may* actually work on Windows, but not on *nix, and you shouldn't do it even on Windows.) In the edited version of your question, you're not doing that, so it's still wrong.

While we're at it, you really don't need to create a `Popen` object and `communicate` with it if that's literally all you're doing. A simpler solution is:

```
print(subprocess.run(['dig', '-x', Adres, '+short'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8'))
```

Also, if you're having problems debugging a complicated expression like yours, it really helps to break it into separate pieces that you can debug separately (with extra `print`s, or debugger breakpoints):

```
proc = subprocess.run(['dig', '-x', Adres, '+short'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
result = proc.stdout.decode('utf-8')
print(result)
```

This is essentially the same thing, with nearly the same efficiency, but easier to read and easier to debug.

And when I run this with `Adres = '156.17.4.20'`, I get exactly the output you're looking for:

```
vpn.ii.uni.wroc.pl.
```

Comment: I see its working but I have list of IP Adress (like 156.17.4.0/24) and i using nettadr. I must put in script all of IP from this mask and in the error i have that problem `TypeError: Can't convert 'IPAddress' object to str implicitly`

Comment: @Gracjan Then use `str(Adres)` in place of `Adres`.

Comment: used and the `print(result)` printing blank line (no errors ??)

Comment: I repair it. I explicitly declared the IP range and working :) Thanks very much :D

Comment: How Can I use | grep in subprocess ? Example : `head = subprocess.run(['HEAD',str_IP,'|','grep','Server'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` returned this same things like `head = subprocess.run(['HEAD',str_IP], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`. How Can I fixed this ? Becouse in console that command shows : `Server: Apache/2.4.6 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1t PHP/5.5.3
`. In Python i can't use this grep

Comment: @Gracjan If you want to use shell piping, then you need to go back to shell=True. But if you read the subprocess docs, they show you how to do the piping from within Python instead, which is usually clearer. And meanwhile, for a simple filter, why do you want to use grep instead of just doing it in Python?

Comment: For example, to keep just the lines containing the sub string ‘Server’ you just add `result = [line for line in result if ‘Server’ in line]`, and then you don’t need to add a whole extra grep and sh into the chain.

Comment: @Gracjan by the way, if you google “Beazley generators for systems” there’s a great presentation on how to do all kinds of fancy filtering on things like this in Python readably and efficiently; he explains things better than I could even if I weren’t limited to SO comments fields.